# python simpy error return with value inside generator

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error, generator, return-value

I got error while running the code below

```
File "simpy.py", line 4
    return 'Monty Pythons Flying Circus'
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

This is a [code sample from simpy official site](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/environments.html)

I tried [this solution given to a similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809390/6540688) but then I got the following error:

```
Invalid yield value "Monty Pythons Flying Circus"
```

The code from the simpy site:

```
import simpy
def my_proc(env):
  yield env.timeout(1)
  return 'Monty Pythons Flying Circus'

env = simpy.Environment()
proc = env.process(my_proc(env))
env.run(until=proc)
```

The modified code I tried as per the solution cited above is given below:

```
import simpy
def my_proc(env):
  yield env.timeout(1)
  yield 'Monty Pythons Flying Circus'
  return
env = simpy.Environment()
proc = env.process(my_proc(env))
env.run(until=proc)
```

This code gave the error `Invalid yield value "Monty Pythons Flying Circus"`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same error and by tracking it to the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/simpy/simpy/src/e84015dcf54c05868712683fb1d9fcfd2cc44089/src/simpy/events.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#events.py-408)
Reading the code and the docstrings of the Process class:

> A generator (also known as a coroutine) can suspend its execution by
>   yielding an event. `Process` will take care of resuming the generator
>   with the value of that event once it has happened.

I understand that the problem is that **you don't yield an event but a String**

Comment: Is there a way to yield a string as an event of some sort? Because I want to yield strings.