# Scrapy - Yield new request not working on loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape a list of Facebook posts. To do it I make the login and then load the list of posts ids to make the requests logging only once.
However, when I try to use the yield to make the requests, it doesn't enter the for loop.

Just for testing I change the yield for a return and it does enter the for loop and call the parse method.

````
``` lang-py
class FacebookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test"
  start_urls = ['https://mbasic.facebook.com']

  def parse(self, response):
  return FormRequest.from_response( response, callback=self.parse_home,
    formxpath='//form[contains(@action, "login")]',
    formdata={'email': "email@email.com", 'pass': "password"}, )

  def parse_home(self, response):
    print(">> parse_home")
    if response.xpath("//div/input[@value='Ok' and @type='submit']"):
      print(">> if condition")
      return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'name_action_selected': 'dont_save'}, callback=self.parse_home, dont_filter=True,)

    for post in [1,2]:
      print(">> for loop")
      href = response.urljoin("/335653391129/posts/10157014203171130".format(post))
      yield scrapy.Request(url=href, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=True,)

  def parse_page(self, response):
    print("____ parse_page  _________")
```
````

Using yield the output was:

```
>> parse_home
>> if condition
```

Only changing the yield to return the output was:

```
>> parse_home
>> if condition
>> parse_home
>> for loop
____ parse_page  _________
```

Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parse_home` method is a generator, you shouldn't use `return [value]` inside a generator. But I tested you code and seems to be working.

More info on [Python SyntaxError: ("'return' with argument inside generator",)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809296/python-syntaxerror-return-with-argument-inside-generator)