# "return" and "return None" behavior difference in generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Simple method with just return keyword returns a `None`

```
def abc():
    return
print(abc())
```

Output: None

Similarly,

```
def abc():
    return None
print(abc())
```

Output: None

However if we use this in generator

```
def abc():
    yield 1
    return None
print(abc())
```

it gives

```
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

where as

```
def abc():
    yield 1
    return
print(abc())
```

gives

```
<generator object abc at 0x7f97d7052b40>
```

Why do we have this difference in behavior?

Comment: It clearly states that return with an argument is a syntax error. The grammar does not check or care whether the argument is None, the SyntaxError already happens before.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa - That is pretty much what the OP is asking, why is there a difference in the behaviour

Comment: You appear to be using an old version of Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use yield with return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215828/why-cant-i-use-yield-with-return)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809390/6699447) is worth of reading

Comment: This hasn't been an error since [Python 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), about *ten years ago*!

Comment: By the way return value of generator does not reach to us. We are using `return` in generators for terminating them.

Answer (score 2):

A bare `return` is useful to break out early from a generator.

Meanwhile `return None` is just a special case of `return <a value>`, and before `yield from` (PEP 380) there was no support or use case for returning a value from a generator. So it was forbidden in order to leave the design space open: by forbidding returning *values* in generators, Python's designers made it possible to allow it later with new semantics as that would not break existing code.

Had they allowed a return value without doing anything with it, there was a risk userland code [would break](https://xkcd.com/1172/). That's why from a forward-compatibility perspective it's often better to *restrict* APIs as much as possible, everything you leave open users will take advantage of, and it becomes risky to change.

Comment: Thanks. Now that it is supported can you add how returning with yield is used to overcome issues you have stated with previous design?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There were no issues in the previous design, it just didn't have any use for returning values from generators so forbid it. Then PEP 380 added a use case for it, and thus allowed it. There is no overcoming, originally forbidding the form allowed enabling it later in a safe and backwards-compatible manner.